# Error while running my package in read only environment

Tags: ora-00600

Is anyone aware of the below error?
Error report -
ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [ktubko_1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
00603. 00000 -  "ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error"
*Cause:    An Oracle server session was in an unrecoverable state.
*Action:   Log in to Oracle again so a new server session will be created
           automatically.  Examine the session trace file for more
           information.

while Executing my package in readonly environment i am getting the above error.

Comment: Ah, without knowing what your package is attempting, we aren't going to be able to offer much help.  However, the 0600-series of errors are internal errors and the DBAs usually get excited when they see them.  A good first step would be to track down your DBA and introduce yourself and mention "trace file".

Comment: Much thanks, i will reach out to my DBA